ActiveMQ Artemis Web Console is not running after build
I have built ActiveMQ Artemis Web console from its repository according to the manual provided in repository.
Build has succeed, although when I'm trying to test run the console, and going to /console path I have a 404 browser error, and the following text in console:
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Closed
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.checkWritable (HttpOutput.java:747)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write (HttpOutput.java:777)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write (OutputStream.java:127)
    at io.hawt.web.filters.BaseTagHrefFilter.doFilter (BaseTagHrefFilter.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter (FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle (ServletHandler.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle (SecurityHandler.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle (ScopedHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle (SessionHandler.java:1580)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle (ScopedHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle (ContextHandler.java:1381)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope (ScopedHandler.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope (ServletHandler.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope (SessionHandler.java:1553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope (ScopedHandler.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope (ContextHandler.java:1303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward (Dispatcher.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward (Dispatcher.java:135)
    at io.hawt.web.auth.Redirector.doForward (Redirector.java:45)
    at io.hawt.web.auth.ClientRouteRedirectFilter.doFilter (ClientRouteRedirectFilter.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter (FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at io.hawt.web.filters.HttpHeaderFilter.doFilter (HttpHeaderFilter.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter (FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at io.hawt.web.filters.HttpHeaderFilter.doFilter (HttpHeaderFilter.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter (FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at io.hawt.web.filters.HttpHeaderFilter.doFilter (HttpHeaderFilter.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter (FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at io.hawt.web.filters.HttpHeaderFilter.doFilter (HttpHeaderFilter.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter (FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at io.hawt.web.filters.HttpHeaderFilter.doFilter (HttpHeaderFilter.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter (FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at io.hawt.web.filters.HttpHeaderFilter.doFilter (HttpHeaderFilter.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter (FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at io.hawt.web.filters.HttpHeaderFilter.doFilter (HttpHeaderFilter.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter (FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at io.hawt.web.filters.HttpHeaderFilter.doFilter (HttpHeaderFilter.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter (FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at io.hawt.web.filters.HttpHeaderFilter.doFilter (HttpHeaderFilter.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter (FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at io.hawt.web.auth.SessionExpiryFilter.process (SessionExpiryFilter.java:89)
    at io.hawt.web.auth.SessionExpiryFilter.doFilter (SessionExpiryFilter.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter (FilterHolder.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter (WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter (FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle (ServletHandler.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle (SecurityHandler.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle (ScopedHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle (SessionHandler.java:1580)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle (ScopedHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle (ContextHandler.java:1381)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope (ScopedHandler.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope (ServletHandler.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope (SessionHandler.java:1553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope (ScopedHandler.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope (ContextHandler.java:1303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle (ContextHandlerCollection.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle (HandlerList.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle (Server.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$RequestDispatchable.dispatch (HttpChannel.java:1598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch (HttpChannel.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle (HttpChannel.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable (HttpConnection.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded (AbstractConnection.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable (FillInterest.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run (SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask (AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask (AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce (AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.run (AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run (ReservedThreadExecutor.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:969)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:1194)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:1149)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:840)

I do not understand why it's happening every time. I was trying to change the Jetty's version, but nothing has changed. Any ideas?

Any feedback here?

TLDR: Try using /console/jolokia instead of just /console.
This worked for me...
Commands for the console:
git clone git@github.com:apache/activemq-artemis-console.gi
cd activemq-artemis-console/
mvn clean install
cd artemis-console-war
mvn jetty:run -Dskip.yarn

Commands for the broker:
wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/activemq/activemq-artemis/2.38.0/apache-artemis-2.38.0-bin.zip
unzip apache-artemis-2.38.0-bin.zip
cd apache-artemis-2.38.0/bin/
./artemis create consoleTest --user myUser --password myPass --require-login
cd consoleTest/bin/
./artemis run

Then I opened http://localhost:8080/console in my browser and added a connection:

Then I added the following connection details:

